# How to make ffmpeg codec componet as OMX component

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make ffmpeg based media player which uses open max il.Basically i want to use ffmpeg h.264 decoder as omx il component and integrate it with android code.
Any pointers on how it can be done.

Mayank

Comment: You can use below as reference,
https://sourceforge.net/projects/omxil/files/components/libomxffmpegdist-0.1.tar.gz/download, here ffmpeg basec decoder is wrapped as omx component (OMX.st.video_decoder.avc") in src/omx_videodec_component.h